# Calculate Angle Similarity - Math - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, angle

I have two normalized angles (in the range of 0 to 360 degrees) and want to compare them using a score from 0 to 1.

For example:

```
var angle1 = 90;
var angle2 = 100;

// Something like this, but with respect to the direction the angles pointing to

var score = 0.9;
```

I came up with the following code:

```
function modulo(x, y){

    return (x % y + y) % y;

}

// Calculates the closest distance between the two angles

var relativeAngle = angle2 - angle1;
relativeAngle = modulo((relativeAngle + 180), 360) - 180;
  
// Converts the result to a score and logs the result
  
console.log(1 - (Math.abs(relativeAngle) / 360));
```

The issue I am having is that 0, 90 gives the same result as 0, 270 (0.75), which is logical but not useful for comparing the angles as they are pointing in opposite directions.

What I am looking for is a method to compare the angles with respect to the orientation using a score from 0 to 1. Does anyone have an idea how I could get this to work? Thanks in advance!

Edit 1, an example:

[image]

In this image the green, yellow and red angles are closer to each other, so they should have a higher similarity.

If I would guess:

red-green = 0.9
red-orange = 0.8

Purple however is about as far from blue as possible.

So the similarity should be something like:

purple-blue = 0.1

Edit 2, how the algorithm should work:

[image]

Comment: If you need orientation information, it would seem logical to me to drop the `abs` and use the `[-1, 1]` interval for the similarity (with proper normalization).

Comment: I thought of that too. However, negative angles would then yield a lower similarity score, than positive angles, making the score useless.

Comment: For context: I am reducing the score of an array of angle-pairs by averaging them.

Comment: Could you share some examples? It's hard to understand what do you want to get as a result, apart from it to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets Added an example.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still wondering what would be the expected result from (0, 90) and (0, 270), if 0.75 does not look right.

Comment: I would like to have a different result for (0, 270) than (0, 90), since they are different angles. 0.75 does not reflect any information about the direction the angles are facing. So if I were to compare the result of (0, 270) with (0, 90), which is both 0.75, it would indicate that they are the same angles.

Comment: Your requirements seem impossible. Suppose `angle1 = 0.0`. Now presumably if `angle2 = 0.0` too, you want a score of `1`. Now increase `angle2` slowly: the score will gradually decrease (it can't increase, because `1` is the max score), and for some positive value of `angle2` it'll be `0.9`, say. But you can also _decrease_ `angle2` slowly starting from `0.0` - again, at some point you'll get something with a score of `0.9` relative to angle1. So assuming that you want the score to be a continuous function of the angles, I don't see a way to meet your requirements.

Comment: And if the score is _not_ a continuous function of the angles, it's going to be a strange beast that doesn't accurately reflect an answer to "how close are these angles to each  other".

Comment: Can you maybe draw a rough graph of how you'd want `score(0.0, angle2)` (i.e., with `angle1` fixed at `0.0`) to look as `angle2` varies from `0.0` through to `360.0`? It's not at all clear what behaviour you want at the moment, and that needs to be sorted out before we can propose actual code.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for the detailed explanation. I was hoping for some formula that could combine the information of similarity and direction into a single score. I will try to draw up how expect the algorithm to work.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but for comparing two angles without having to care about orientations or normalisations, I like the formula `cos(0.5*(angle1 - angle2))**2`. That gives a value of `1` when `angle1` and `angle2` are equal (modulo 2*π), and a value of `0` when they're diametrically opposite. But it's not going to distinguish orientations.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Added it to my question. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I really did mean draw a graph - a line graph with `angle2` on the x-axis, going from 0 to 360 degrees, and with the similarity score on the y-axis, showing how `similarity_score(0.0, angle2)` varies with `angle2`. I think by trying to sketch that graph, you'll understand why we're saying that your requirements are impossible to satisfy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it seems you want to somehow distill average orientation and separation together into a single value. I'm not sure that's possible due to aliasing (which you hint at in your question).

Comparing a pair of angles as you describe is simply calculating their minimum angle of separation.

However, comparing two sets of angles in the way you describe also needs to take into account the difference in the relative orientation between the two sets. Since each pair could be converted to a [separation, orientation] pair, two pairs could be scored relatively based on Cartesian distance.

```js
// Smallest difference between angles as on a circle
// range [0, 1)
const angle = (a,b) => {
  const results = a > b ? a - b : b - a;
  return (results > 180 ? 360 - results : results) / 180;
}

// Midway between two angles as on a circle
// range [0, 1)
const direction = (a,b) => {
  const large = (a > b ? a - b : b - a) > 180;
  const results = (a + b) / 2;
  return (results + (large ? (results >= 180 ? -180 : 180 ) : 0)) / 180;
};

// Cartesian distance score
// range [0, 1)
// x is angle, y is direction
const distance = (x0, y0, x1, y1) => {
  // direction wraps around so account for that
  if((y0 > y1 ? y0 - y1 : y1 - y0) > 0.5) y0 += 1;

  // the `*2` is because the wrap-around distance is never more than half the interval. 
  return Math.sqrt((x0-x1)**2 + ((y0-y1)*2)**2) / Math.SQRT2;
}

// Difference score for two angles, a and b
const diff = (a,b) => angle(a, b);

// Difference score for two pairs of angles [[a0, b0], [a1, b1]]
const diff2 = (a0, b0, a1, b1) => distance(
  angle(a0, b0), direction(a0, b0),
  angle(a1, b1), direction(a1, b1)
);
```

Comment: I think the intervals are [0, 1) but I'm not 100% sure. They might be [0, 1].

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I just tested it and it seems to return the correct values.

Comment: I noticed some issues with the "direction" calculation and behavior so fixed those. Direction wraps around so that wrap-around needs to be accounted for in `direction()` and `distance()`. Otherwise there would be an artifact in the scoring when the pairs are close to but on opposite sides of the 360/0 crossover.